# Make a discord bot say something on voice channel

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

i couldn't find a solution for this so here i am.
I made a bot in discord.py rewrite for my discord server and i wanted to implement the feature where my bot says something when a user joins the voice channel.

I couldn't even make the bot join the voice chat because it gives every error possible. Thanks in advance.

These is what i tried:

```
@bot.command()
async def join_voice(self, ctx):
    connected = ctx.author.voice
    if connected:
        await connected.channel.connect()
```

and this

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    channel = author.voice_channel
    await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

they both give this error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception:
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! With your question, could you include some of the code you tried as well as any errors you may have been given so we can help you better?

Answer (score 1):

## SOLUTION

Ok big news. I figured out how to connect.

You need to have PyNaCl (which i didn't install).

I also debugged a little and found out voice_channel didn't exist in author and i replaced it with voice.channel.

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    channel = author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    print("i'm in the voice channel")


@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    print("i'm out of the voice channel")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing discord.py with voice support:

```
# Linux/macOS
python3 -m pip install -U "discord.py[voice]"

# Windows
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives me the same errors, in both commands. This time they both seems to give the same error. I just updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

change `author.voice_channel` to `author.voice.channel`
you need to join the voice channel before you use the command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).